# In Bootstrap 3, is it possible to use col-*-* classes on definition terms with horizontal definition lists?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

For the following markup:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>A few words describing the term</dt>
    <dd>The data associated with the term</dd>
</dl>
```

The `dt` term element is fixed width (at 180px) and cannot be changed with `col-` due to specificity of CSS. For example, the below does not work:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt class="col-sm-3">A few words describing the term</dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-9">The data associated with the term</dd>
</dl>
```

Description lists are for name-value pairs and a fixed width is not suitable for some languages where the single word term is longer than 180px. Truncating is not possible (it truncates valuable meaning) and word-wrapping (using Stack Overflow overrides) is not readable.

Do I need to add extra classes or should I chase up with Twitter Bootstrap?

### Edit

Given the lack of answers, I have opened an issue with bootstrap:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14983

Answer (score 1):

...you can always write overwrite code for the col-sm-3 and col-sm-9 classes (following the exact example), but I guess it would be easier to write your own classes using media queries and the same breakpoints you are using in your bootstrap file. You can also use this custom class to set a new minimum width.

```
@media (min-width:XXX) and (max-width:XXX) {
  dt.col-sm-3 {
    width:25%;
  }
  dt.col-sm-9 {
    width:75%;
  }
}
```